# Scanner trouble. No script errors but console gives errors

Tags: java.util.scanner

I am working on a personal project but i have a problem i cant seem to figure out.

```
public void setvars() {
    File file = new File("config.txt");

    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
            //int OESID = sc.nextInt(); this variable isnt used yet.
            String refresh = sc.next();
            sc.close();

            textFieldtest.setText(refresh);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In the console its telling me the error is with `while(sc.hasNextLine()) {` I cant figure it out. Any pointers/advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is the error?  What is the `Scanner` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're closing the Scanner while you're still using it.

Modify your code to close the Scanner once you're done with it:

```
    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        //int OESID = sc.nextInt(); this variable isnt used yet.
        String refresh = sc.next();

        textFieldtest.setText(refresh);
    }
    sc.close();
```

This should probably be a general pattern whenever you're dealing with any resource - ensure you close it only once you're sure you dont need it anymore.

You can make your life even easier if you're using Java 7 by using the new try-with-resource functionality, which will auto-close resources:

```
    try(Scanner sc = new Scanner("/Users/sean/IdeaProjects/TestHarness/src/TestHarness.java")) {
        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
            // do your processing here
        }
    }  // resource will be closed when this block is finished
```